# GitLab: Print just groupID by name_group

Tags: gitlab

I would like to get groupid by  name_group and save this in a variable.

e.g

- Search for group:

curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXXXXXX" http://gitserver/api/v3/groups?search=test_group

Command of above gives me a .json output where are all details of the group however I would like to get just the ID and save this in a variable for creating a script.

Thanks!

Comment: you can pipe the json into jq utility and retrieve the necessary field from the json . example: http://www.compciv.org/recipes/cli/jq-for-parsing-json/

Answer (score 0):

That's work for me:

http://www.compciv.org/recipes/cli/jq-for-parsing-json/

Although I had to use the next code to get my id:

`cat id_group.json | jq '.[0] .id'`

Thanks!